# Set theory properties of relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

Given the set  $X=\{\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$

Show that the relation $$ \subseteq $$
on $X$ is reflexive, anti-symmetrical and transitive.

What do these properties mean in this context given that it's a set of sets?

I understand how it would be done if it were a set such as $X=\{(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)\}$ and so on.

Comment: A relation on $X$ is a subset of $X^2$ (with particular properties). In this case, the relation being described is $\{(A,B)\in X^2\colon A\subseteq B\}$. So for example, $(\{1\},\{1,3\})$ is an element of that relation, but $( \{1,2\}, \{2,3\} )$ is not.

Comment: Thank you. Basically first we have the Cartesian product of X times itself. Then we reduce that set to elements that fit the subset symbol, hence ({1},{1,3} but not ({1,2,},{2,3}). Then we want to check if the existing elements (that satisfy A is a subset of B) are reflexive/anti-symmetrical/transitive. Is my understanding correct this far?

Then, if we have ({1},{1,3}) we need to have ({1,3},{1}). since we have to show that it is reflexive. But {1,3} is not a subset of {1} therefore it doesn't exist. Therefore the set is not reflexive?

Comment: Therefore the set is anti-symmetrical* (not reflexive).

Answer (score 1):

It is a strange exercise but, anyway here are my two cents:

- Notice that the elements of $X$ are sets (subsets rather) contained in the set $\{1,2,3\}$
- $A$ and $B$ are related by "$\subseteq$" if and only if $x\in A$ implies that $x\in B$.

That the  relation $ \subseteq $ has the desired properties follows by checking that

1. $A\subseteq A$ for set $A$ that appears in $X$.
2. $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$ implies that $A=B$ for any $A$ and $B$ that appear in $X$
3. $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq C$ implies that $A\subseteq C$ for all $A,B,C$ in $X$.

Properties 1-3 of course are valid not only for the elements of $X$ for any collection of subsets of a set.